# Sharing a Photo on Facebook Timeline instead of Profile Picture: Android

Tags: facebook, android-studio

I am successfully sharing photos on Facebook timeline through my Android app since past several months. Yesterday, I came to know about that when a user share photo using app, it makes this photo as profile picture instead of posting on timeline as it was. I reviewed, debugged the code and observed that resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName returns "com.facebook.timeline.stagingground.ProfilePictureShareActivity" package. That's why it sharing photo as profile picture now. Here is my code:

```
try {
     resolveInfo = ActivityFinder.getActivityInfo(WatermarkActivity.this, Intent.ACTION_SEND, "image/*", "facebook");
     Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     photoIntent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
     photoIntent.setType("image/*");
     photoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + fsTMPPhotoFileName));
     startActivity(photoIntent);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Does anybody else faced the similar issue ever? Any assistance to fix this issue will be highly appreciated? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, a long time ago, but didn't posted the answer. Now, I am posting answer, in case, anyone experience such issue. The only issue was, instead of setClassName(...) passing packageName and class with photoIntent, just to setPackage(...) and passing packageName. Here is the final code.

```
try {

   Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   photoIntent.setPackage(riInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
   photoIntent.setType("image/*");
   photoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + fsTMPPhotoFileName));
   startActivity(photoIntent);

} 
catch (Exception e) {

     ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

That's all.